# DATENAME not working with Group By

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query that returns data as expected:

```
 SELECT intMonth as Month
, intYear AS Year,
Sum([intExposureHours]) as [Total Hours]
  FROM tblSSQReleaseToMajor RTM 
  INNER JOIN tblCompany C On RTM.CompanyID = C.CompanyID
    AND C.bitActive = 1 
  INNER JOIN [tblIncidentDetailByOperatorByMonth] BM ON RTM.MajorID = BM.OperatorID
    AND BM.ContractorID = RTM.CompanyID 
        AND BM.OperatorID = 47792
    AND BM.intYear = 2017
        Group By intMonth, intYear
```

[image]

However, when I try to change the numerical Month to the Month Name like this:

```
SELECT DateName(month,intMonth) as Month
, intYear AS Year,
Sum([intExposureHours]) as [Total Hours]
  FROM tblSSQReleaseToMajor RTM 
  INNER JOIN tblCompany C On RTM.CompanyID = C.CompanyID
    AND C.bitActive = 1 
  INNER JOIN [tblIncidentDetailByOperatorByMonth] BM ON RTM.MajorID = BM.OperatorID
    AND BM.ContractorID = RTM.CompanyID 
        AND BM.OperatorID = 47792
    AND BM.intYear = 2017
        Group By intMonth, intYear
```

I get this:

[image]

Changing the "Group By" Clause to "`Group By DateName(month,intMonth), intYear`"

Produces this:

[image]

Can anyone tell me why I am not getting January, February, March, April May?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add the DBMS tag

Comment: I tried that.  That is the 2nd example.

Comment: Because DATENAME wants a date as second param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DATENAME only works with actual dates. You have to do something hacky to get this to work.

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, intMonth - 1, CAST('2017-01-01' AS DATETIME))) as Month
, intYear AS Year,
Sum([intExposureHours]) as [Total Hours]
  FROM tblSSQReleaseToMajor RTM 
  INNER JOIN tblCompany C On RTM.CompanyID = C.CompanyID
    AND C.bitActive = 1 
  INNER JOIN [tblIncidentDetailByOperatorByMonth] BM ON RTM.MajorID = BM.OperatorID
    AND BM.ContractorID = RTM.CompanyID 
        AND BM.OperatorID = 47792
    AND BM.intYear = 2017
        Group By intMonth, intYear
```

Edit: Sorry, to answer your question of why this is happening, try these queries:

```
SELECT CAST(1 AS DATETIME) -- 1900-01-02 00:00:00.000
SELECT CAST(42919 AS DATETIME) -- is today, the 42,919th day since January 1, 1900
```

SQL Server actually stores dates as integers. When you put '1' as a date, it sees that as "1900-01-02 00:00:00.000". Therefore it says the month is January for all of your results because you're inputting the numbers 1-12. It thinks you're saying January 2-13, 1900. That's why it grabs January for each one.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That makes a ton of sense now!